# Uploading my Drupal Comerce Files to My Web Host

Tags: database

I have installed Drupal Commerce using Kickstart.  It is now running on my local server.  How to I properly upload and configure it on my Web Host?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File Transfer tools like WinSCP, FileZilla to transfer you files in your webhost. Then you need to export your database in your local then import in your webhost database. If you have some special configuration like path you may need to update that in your webhost.

1. Create a database creds in your webhost.
2. Export you local database and import it on webhost.
3. Upload your Drupal files
4. Update your settings.php to change the database information.

   ....